# Do I need to apply sub div before sculpting with multires

Tags: modeling, texturing, sculpting

I've modeled an object with subdivision. I've now unwrapped its UVs and textured it  and I'm bringing it into sculpt mode to sculpt some details. My question is, do I need to apply my subdivision surface when sculpting with multiresolution?

Comment: Hello, do you mean that you are using a Subdivision Surface modifier before the Mutlires? Could you please show a screenshot? It would help to understand...

Comment: Yes, in the modifiy stack I first have the Multires and below Subdivision surface

Comment: If it makes no difference to apply the Subdivision Surface, don't, of course your object will stay low-poly, but if it's not a problem for your sculpt, then it's ok

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!